# Configure the records of model as unique not duplicate with each other

Tags: django

I have a tag model which relate to articles with many-to-many relationship:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("id",)

class Article(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I want to make sure the tags are unique and not duplicate,but found it's difficult

```
In [39]: article.tags.create(name="django", owner=article.owner)
Out[39]: <Tag: django>
In [40]: article.tags.create(name="django", owner=article.owner)
Out[40]: <Tag: django>
In [41]: article.tags.create(name="django", owner=article.owner)
Out[41]: <Tag: django>
In [42]: article.tags.all()
Out[42]: <QuerySet [<Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: django>]>
In [43]: Tag.objects.all()
Out[43]: <QuerySet [<Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, <Tag: django>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

How to configure the recodes of Tag as unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniqueness can be specified at the [field level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique) by adding `unique=True` to your field definition, e.g.:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

or at the [model level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) using the `Meta` attribute `unique_together` for constraints on multiple fields, e.g.:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ("id",)
    unique_together = ("name", "owner")
```